# Thread safety of enum valueOf()

Tags: java, enums, thread-safety, value-of

This is a variation of the perpertual **"lengthy-if or switch"** dilemma...

Consider a multithreaded application using a static method that contains a long (over a dozen conditions) `if` statement, which checks the type of an object and returns a value accordingly, i.e. something like

```
public static String checkType(Class<?> type)
{
    if (type == A.class)
    {
        return aString;
    }
    else if (type == B.class)
    {
        return bString;
    }
    ...
    else if (type == z.class)
    {
        return zString;
    }
}
```

Obviously a switch statement is not directly applicable here, so a common pattern is to have an `enum` and call its `valueOf()`, i.e. do something like

```
public enum Strings
{
    A(aString), B(bString), ..., Z(zString)

    private final String value;

    private Strings(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String value()
    {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

So, `checkType()` could be re-written as

```
public static String checkType(Class<?> type)
{
    return Strings.valueOf(getActualTypeName(type.getClass().getName())).value();
}
```

with appropriate checks for `null` values added in production code and some String processing for non-primitive types, inside the `getActualTypeName()` method, to retrieve the actual type name from strings like `"class java.lang.Long"` (for primitives, the `getName()` method returns the expected string, e.g. "`long"`).

However, if `valueOf()` is not thread-safe, this will not work in a concurrent environment. The same applies to using a (normal) `Map` object and probably these two alternatives are variants of the same pattern, since `enum.valueOf()` is apparently based on

```
Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)
```

which calls

```
enumType.enumConstantDirectory().get(name);
```

in the `Class.java` class.

The `enumConstantDirectory()` method, every time invoked, returns a new `HashMap`, created from a copy of the `values()` array.

Would that be thread safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find any reasons why `enum.valueOf(String)` would not be thread safe:

- strings are immutable, so the argument can't be mutated while `valueOf` does its job
- valueOf checks the argument vs. the names of the enum constants and they are all static and final

What makes you think that `enum.valueOf()` is not thread safe?

**EDIT**

valueOf calls:

```
T result = enumType.enumConstantDirectory().get(name);
```

where `enumType` is your enum class.

enumConstantDirectory() uses this pattern:

```
Map<String, T> enumConstantDirectory() {
    if (enumConstantDirectory == null) {
        T[] universe = getEnumConstantsShared();
        if (universe == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                getName() + " is not an enum type");
        Map<String, T> m = new HashMap<>(2 * universe.length);
        for (T constant : universe)
            m.put(((Enum<?>)constant).name(), constant);
        enumConstantDirectory = m;
    }
    return enumConstantDirectory;
}
```

where `enumConstantDirectory` is a volatile variable:

```
private volatile transient Map<String, T> enumConstantDirectory = null;
```

Imagine a thread arriving concurrently in that method:

- if `enumConstantDirectory` is null (there is no visibility issue here because it is volatile), it will construct the map and assign it to that variable. Because of the volatile guarantees, all other threads, from that point in time, will see the map fully constructed.
- if another thread arrives in the method at the same time and also observe a null value of `enumConstantDirectory`, it will recreate the map and safely publish it again

The worst case scenario here is that 2 threads could potentially be using 2 different maps (different instances) but their content will be the same so it would not cause any issues.

**Bottom line**: there is no way that a thread could see a map which is half constructed, because the map construction is done on a local variable, which is assigned to the volatile variable **after** it has been populated.

Comment: If it extends Enum.valueOf(), then it looks up non-synchronized map. Have a look at the source of the Enum.valueOf() method; it calls enumType.enumConstantDirectory().get(name).

Comment: @PNS If you look deeper, you will see that `enumConstantDirectory` (the variable) is volatile, so that provides enough guarantee to make sure that the map is safely published and never changes after construction. The worst case is that the map gets created more than once, but since its creation is based on final states, it is deterministic so the lazy pattern used makes it thread safe.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to suppose that `Enum.valueOf()` is not thread-safe.  It does not mutate anything, and it is only accessing state in the actual `enum` class that is effectively final.

If this method *was* non-thread-safe, I think there would be something in the javadocs to say so.

Comment: If it extends Enum.valueOf(), then it looks up non-synchronized map. Have a look at the source of the Enum.valueOf() method; it calls enumType.enumConstantDirectory().get(name).

Comment: lookups in a non-synchronized map are perfectly safe if it's read-only.

Comment: @stevevls only if the map has been safely published.

Answer (score 1):

May be I am wrong but it seems there is a subtle issue here:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType,
                                                       String name) {
     T result = enumType.enumConstantDirectory().get(name);
     if (result != null)
           return result;
     if (name == null)
           throw new NullPointerException("Name is null");
     throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                     "No enum constant " + enumType.getCanonicalName() + "." + name);
}
```

This is the code for valueOf. It uses the passed in `enumType` to create an internal `HashMap` with the constants and the code is not `sychronized`.
There seems a subtle issue here: `T result = enumType.enumConstantDirectory().get(name);`
The `enumConstantDirectory()` does a check for `enumConstantDirectory == null` but it is not synchronized, in order to create the `HashMap`. Perhaps the side-effects are not important (I don't know what info the `Class` stores) but in any case it is surely safe as long as `enumType` is not shared in your application code

Comment: I don't think so: `enumConstantDirectory()` is lazily created using a volatile variable that IMO guarantees that it is safely published.

Comment: @assylias:I may be wrong here, but doesn't that guarantee only visibility?There are no synchronization guarantees

Comment: See my edited answer, you are right. so the map could get created more than once, and 2 threads could observe different map instances, but all threads will observe a valid map (it contains the correct keys/values).